# How to convert a mysql-platform specific query to non-platform specific?

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, cross-platform

I have a MySQL-platform specific query:

```
SELECT month(from_unixtime(s.date)) AS month, count(s.id) AS blah, s.status 
    FROM Something s 
    WHERE s.date between unix_timestamp($blah1) and unix_timestamp($blah2) 
    GROUP BY s.status, month
```

I used some MySQL platform specific commands like `month`, `from_unixtime` and `unix_timestamp`.
How can I re-write this query to make it cross-platform compatible that it works on Postgres too?

Comment: Answer: Yes, you can!

Comment: Please don't spam comments! I asked how to re-write the query.

Comment: BTW: `WHERE s.date between unix_timestamp($blah) and unix_timestamp($blah) ` is complete nonsense, even in mysql. ( `WHERE s.date = unix_timestamp($blah)` would do the same )

Comment: Sorry I meant two dates. Edited.

Comment: The ANSI SQL (or Postgres) solution would not work with MySQL.

Comment: Ok. Please just advise how to re-write it to get it worked just for postgre. Thanks.

Comment: Note: it's Postgres, PostgreSQL or just PG. Never "postgre"

Comment: What wildplasser and a_horse_with_no_name are trying to explain it that MySQL uses its own SQL dialect which is NOT compatible with any other RDBMS including Postgres (or PostgreSQL). You will have to create the ANSI functions in MySQL that use MySQL functions behind the scene. (or you can create MySQL functions in Postgres). Good luck.

Comment: How to create ANSI functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are storing a "unix epoch" value in the column `date`, the following should work:

```
SELECT extract(month from to_timestamp(s.date)) AS month, 
       count(s.id) AS blah, 
       s.status 
FROM Something s 
WHERE s.date between to_timestamp($blah1) and to_timestamp($blah2) 
GROUP BY s.status, month
```

[`to_timestamp()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) with a double (or integer) parameter converts a unix epoch to a proper timestamp.

The real question however is: why aren't you using a proper `timestamp` data type?

Comment: I am using linux timestamp with php's time(). Isn't it a proper timestamp? What exactly you mean by proper timestamp? You mean date()?

Comment: Please give a sample format of proper timestamp how does it look like?

Comment: to_timestamp and extract and month are postgres platform specific?

Comment: How to create ANSI functions?

Comment: @user4271704: `extract()` is ANSI SQL, but there is no ANSI function to convert seconds to a proper timestamp. If you want to stay "ANSI compatible" use a proper `timestamp` column instead of storing a timestamp as an integer.

Comment: Please give a sample format how a proper timestamp look like?

Comment: @user4271704 `create table foo (id integer, ..., created_at timestamp)`. `timestamp` is an ANSI SQL data type. More details in the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html

Comment: You said ```extract``` is ANSI. I asked if ```month``` is ANSI too? Why I don't see ```enum``` as field type in phpPgAdmin nor in pgAdmin? How to have enum with postgres?

Comment: The **complete** extract function _including_ the parameter `month` (or `day` or `year`, ...) is ANSI SQL. Please see the manual for creating an enum: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtype.html#AEN80718